# Android: get images from gallery, display them in recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So i want to choose some images from gallery then display these images inside recyclerview , layout of image inside recyclerview would have a rotate button to rotate images before uploading to firebase.

now i would like to knew how to get display images from galelry inside recyclerview so i can rotate them and  upload the rotated images for firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider following steps:

1. Fire an intent to select images from gallery.
2. You can access the images by overloading the onActivityResult() function.
3. Now, you have to save those images using the URIs provided for the images.
4. Use those images on your recycler view.
5. Upload them to firebase when the rotation is done.